# Geoprocessing tool- Add Incrementing ID Field without ArcSDE?

Tags: arcgis-pro

I am trying to create a unique field in my flood zone polygon feature class. I think my best option would be to use the geoprocessing tool 'add incrementing ID Field' in ArcGIS Pro. I keep getting: "ERROR 000186  Only support datasets served through ArcSDE"

I don't think my academic account has ArcSDE, and I'm curious if anyone knows a workaround to this, so that each of my polygons within the feature class have their own unique ID in a field I want to title 'source_id'.

Comment: Sequences are a feature of RDBMSes. You can't create a sequence in file geodatabase or and other file-based format without an RDBMS engine.  You can populate your own unique values, but only by maintaining it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

So you want a field which contains a unique value for each feature in the feature class.

There is already a unique id on your fc called ObjectID (or OID). And most GP tools transfer the ObjectID value to the output feature class as a field named ORIG_FID (typically).

So you may review if you really need this. If you still do here's some options

##### Re-use the record's ObjectID value

As I said, ObjectID is there already and is guaranteed unique, so you could just transfer those values to unique_id.  Be aware there could be gaps in the values, eg: `1, 2, 52345, 52346`.

Process: Use **AddField** to add a new field named unique_id (of type Long), then use **CalculateField** to transfer the values from ObjectID to unique_id.

##### Calculate sequential value

Calculate a sequential ID or number based on an interval.

Process: Use **AddField** to add a new field named unique_id (of type Long), then use **CalculateField** to set values from 1 to n for each record (sequentially).

See "Accumulative and sequential calculations" on the doc page [ArcGIS Pro/Calculate Field Python examples](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/calculate-field-examples.htm)

##### Others

There's some other options also, using a GUID value, etc... but two above fit most people's needs.